# Trigger Notification to Public Group when Agent Raises a flag to notify their supervisor

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, chat

In Salesforce chat we can Raise a flag to notify your supervisor you need help. When an agent raises the flag, the supervisor will be updated in the omni supervisor agent summary view.

We want to send a notification (Email) to all supervisors once the flag is raised.

According to the docs, there is a standard object called LiveAgentSession.  But this only seems to have sessions that have been completed, not existing sessions. Is there a way to see the existing sessions.

You can access LiveAgent events through the API. There's a call that returns current session data: ChasitorSessionData.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_livechattranscriptevent.htm

I am not sure how I could trigger a flow or apex method on these events.